# Automatic OCR Document Capture Security Risks

Tags: email, exchange

We have recently implemented an automated OCR, email scanning program that connects to our exchange email service, This service will open attached invoice and insert them into our accounting software program automatically. This program is installed and run on one of our VM's on the same subnet as our production machines.

The company implementing has asked for us to bypass our exchange spam and malware filters for the email addresses used for this service. My question is if someone sends an email with malicious content either within the HTML or PDF its self, would this actually cause the malicious code to execute and what other security risks could this create?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question for your vendor, although it may not be easy to get a helpful answer out of them.  This is really no different than asking, "We're running a website, and it accepts connections from the internet.  Is it possible that an attacker can send malicious code that allows them to execute code on the application server?"

**Is it possible?**
Of course.

**Is it a practical risk?**
Probably not but it's impossible for us to say.

The person best able to assess the likelihood of a vulnerability is a vendor.  You could also hire a professional to perform a security assessment or penetration test (with the vendor's permission, presumably).  No one here can tell you the likelihood of an actual issue though, anymore than you could tell me how easy it would be to break into my home.

Answer (score -2):

Malware will run on the server that it was opened, if it is running on your vm the user running the app/service will have that on their account

Comment: Is there any way to improve what we're currently doing then?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Nor is it particularly accurate. A machine is for instance not fallible to social engineering, so it shouldn't accept `invoice.pdf.exe`. Furthermore, the OCR library may not use a PDF rendering library that is common in desktop software, thus less of a target. And so forth. In short: even if malicious attachments reaches the software, there may be mitigations that stop it from delivering the payload.